# How do I get Juypter Widgets to render properly through Sphinx and nbconvert?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nbconvert, jupyter-widget

I am using Jupyter widgets in my notebooks. My notebooks are then processed through [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/) + [nbsphinx](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to generate HTML. I noticed that even the simple example below shows a slider in my notebook (on Jupyter Lab), but the generated, corresponding HTML page does not show the slider.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

widgets.IntSlider()
```

I know there is a way to get the widget to render from observing the published HTML of [Juypter Widgets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Basics.html#Using-widgets). Their book is built using Sphinx + nbsphinx. When I look at their [Sphinx configuration](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/blob/80921ac9f9a18c43b02918ce3913818c188ae34c/docs/source/conf.py), they have the following extensions enabled.

```
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.autosummary',
    'sphinx.ext.intersphinx',
    'sphinx.ext.mathjax',
    'nbsphinx',
    'jupyter_sphinx.execute',
    'IPython.sphinxext.ipython_console_highlighting',
]
```

I believe the key to rendering widgets from a notebook to the published HTML is the `jupyter_sphinx.execute` extension. My project's extensions are as follows. Note that when issuing `make html` there is a warning to change `jupyter_sphinx.execute` to `jupyter_sphinx` (it does not matter, however, as using either still does not render the widgets).

```
extensions = [
    'sphinxcontrib.bibtex',
    'nbsphinx',
    'sphinx.ext.mathjax',
    'sphinx_sitemap',
    'jupyter_sphinx'
]
```

Issuing the command `pip list` I see the following packages.

```
jupyter-client                     6.1.3
jupyter-console                    6.1.0
jupyter-core                       4.6.3
jupyter-server-proxy               1.5.0
jupyter-sphinx                     0.3.2
jupyterlab                         2.1.4
jupyterlab-commenting-service      0.2
jupyterlab-server                  1.1.5
nbconvert                          6.0.7
nbsphinx                           0.8.0
sphinx-autobuild                   2020.9.1
sphinx-rtd-theme                   0.5.0
sphinx-sitemap                     2.2.0
sphinxcontrib-applehelp            1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-bibtex               1.0.0
sphinxcontrib-blockdiag            2.0.0
sphinxcontrib-devhelp              1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp             1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-jsmath               1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp               1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml      1.1.4
sphinxcontrib-websupport           1.2.2
```

If you look at their `ipynb` [source code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/80921ac9f9a18c43b02918ce3913818c188ae34c/docs/source/examples/Widget%20Basics.ipynb), all you see is `widgets.IntSlider()` in one of the cells (there's nothing special happening). According to nbconvert, [live rendering of widgets](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html?highlight=widget#id53) has been available since version 4.3.

Any ideas on what additional configuration or steps I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution was easier than I thought. In Jupyter Lab, go to `Settings > Save Widget State Automatically` and make sure that option is checked.

Alternatively, you can go to `~/.jupyter/lab/user-settings/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager/plugin.jupyterlab-settings` and configure the settings as follows.

```
{
    // Jupyter Widgets
    // @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager:plugin
    // Jupyter widgets settings.
    // ******************************************

    // Save Jupyter widget state in notebooks
    // Automatically save Jupyter widget state when a notebook is saved.
    "saveState": true
}
```

The solution was not so clear, but this [page](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/embedding.html) gave me some hints.